# GitHub API: what API calls unauthenticated users are permitted to make?

Tags: github-api

We have to find the answer to this question as part of a course and we can't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unauthenticated users are allowed to use the GitHub API to fetch publicly available data. Unauthenticated requests can't be used to fetch private data or create/modify/delete any data (public or private).